# PHP Print Server

Tags: php, printing

Is there any way how we can find out the number of prints taken from a printer, when all we have is the database containing the IP Addresses of printers in the organization, and the client IPs connected to the different printers? This needs to be done using PHP. Also, the database needs to be automatically updated whenever a new print is fired from the printer.

Comment: This will totally depend on the printer used. You'll have to look into the manual and/or ask vendor support to see whether there is an interface you can connect to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

network printers have usually a web interface where you can connect and configure the server or read the statistics like "pages printed"...
I would extend the database with user/password and printer type and write a php class which can connect to the web interface and read the printed pages count information with regex.